# How to create a collection of objects and add to the collection on each loop iteration using C# ASP.NET Forum

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How to create a collection of objects and add to the collection on each loop iteration using C# ASP.NET Forum. Actually base on para `ID' getting user information in xl. But when I am going to download export to xl only first row record is showing in xl. But other selected is not getting in xl, I am confused in foreach loop. I want to download all data which match base on ID condition and selected in gridview. I am very weak in collection concept. I want to export to xl on gridview selected rows base on ID. Already working but only first record only coming in datatable.

Below is my export to xl button code:

```
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        foreach (GridViewRow row1 in gv_TotalAllReg.Rows)
        {
            if (row1.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                bool isChecked = ((CheckBox)row1.FindControl("chk_box")).Checked;
                if (isChecked == true)
                {

                   int index = row1.RowIndex;

                    bo.Para1 = "4";
                    bo.Para2 = "Innovation";

                    bo.Para3 = gv_TotalAllReg.DataKeys[index].Values[0].ToString();//Id
                    dt = bl.Admin_GetInnovationbaseonParaType(bo);


                    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                    ds.Tables.Add(dt);

                }

            }


        }


        if (gv_TotalAllReg.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            ExcelHelper.ToExcel(ds, "ApplicationDetails.xls", Page.Response);
            btnExport.Visible = true;

        }
```

Comment: any buddy for help to resolve this issue?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the Excel export function you're using only exports the first DataTable in the DataSet.

Maybe try something like this:

```
DataTable dt = null;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
foreach (GridViewRow row1 in gv_TotalAllReg.Rows)
{
    if (row1.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        bool isChecked = ((CheckBox)row1.FindControl("chk_box")).Checked;
        if (isChecked == true)
        {
            int index = row1.RowIndex;
            bo.Para1 = "4";
            bo.Para2 = "Innovation";
            bo.Para3 = gv_TotalAllReg.DataKeys[index].Values[0].ToString();//Id
            var tempdt = bl.Admin_GetInnovationbaseonParaType(bo);
            if (dt == null) 
            {
                dt = tempdt.Clone();
            }

            foreach(DataRow temprow in tempdt.Rows) 
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(temprow.ItemArray);
            }
        }
    }    
}

if (dt == null) 
{
    dt = new DataTable();
}
ds.Tables.Add(dt);

if (gv_TotalAllReg.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    ExcelHelper.ToExcel(ds, "ApplicationDetails.xls", Page.Response);
    btnExport.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Can you update all answer because getting confused. @WithMetta

Comment: Just did. Try that.

Comment: getting this error: Additional information: This row already belongs to another table. @WithMetta

Comment: I changed dt.Rows.Add(temprow); to dt.Rows.Add(temprow.ItemArray);

Try that.

Comment: now getting this error: Additional information: Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table. @ WithMetta

Comment: now getting this error: CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ItemArray' and no extension method 'ItemArray' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) . @WithMetta

Comment: I tried making another tweak. Let me know if you have success. I also changed "var temprow" to "DataRow temprow".

Comment: getting this error: Additional information: Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table. on line  dt.Rows.Add(temprow.ItemArray); . @WithMetta

Comment: Same first row only downloading please help. @WithMetta

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144268/discussion-between-withmetta-and-mazhar-124).

Comment: sorry the above code perfect solve my problem. @WithMetta